# Rails models: Validates a number attribute is not eq to zero

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a column that can be either positive or negative, but never zero. I'm doing the following which doesn't seem to work:

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :amount, presence: true
  validates :amount, :numericality => { :not_equal_to => 0 }
  .
  .
  .
```

This is my test

```
let(:transaction) { FactoryGirl.build(:transaction) }

it "is invalid if amount is zero" do
  transaction.amount = 0
  expect(transaction).to have(1).error_on(:amount)
end
```

This is my factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :transaction do
    sequence(:description) { |n| "Transaction #{n}" }
    category_id nil
    amount -100
    notes nil
    fund_id 1
  end
end
```

What's the way to check number is either positive or negative? Is there something else I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `:other_than`, not `:not_equal_to`

```
validates :amount, :numericality => { :other_than => 0 }
```

See the [documentation on `validates_numericality_of`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_numericality_of) for all the options.